# How to access Apollo useMutaion response

Tags: graph, apollo, react-apollo

When I do a mutation with useMutation hook, I can console.log my data but I cannot save the data object in a localState. I don't know what am I  missing. Any help is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```js
//Schema file

startTest(identifier: String): TestResponse
```

the mutation payload is as follows:

```js
  type TestResponse {
    errorCode: Int
    errorMessage: String
    success: Boolean
    transactionId: ID
    version: Int
  }
```

In the resolver I hardcoded the following data return:

```js
    startTest(_, { identifier }) {
      console.log("hello from server");
      return {
        errorCode: 0,
        errorMessage: null,
        success: true,
        transactionId: "d2984911-bbc4-4e6a-9103-96ca934f6ed3",
        version: 0,
      };
    },
```

In component folder I've triggered the mutation with a button click.

```js
const [startTestt, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(
    START_FIRE_DAMPER_TEST,
    {
      onCompleted: ({ startFireDampersTest }) =>
        console.log(startFireDampersTest.success),
        useState(startFireDampersTest.success)
       
    },

    {
      onError: () => console.log("error!"), // never gets called
    }
  );

  console.log(result); // undefined

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  if (data && data.startFireDampersTest)
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Success!</p>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre> // I can see string object but how to render the element of the object inside the component??
      </div>
    );


  const triggerTest = () => {
    startTest({ variables: { identifier: "0000000" } });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Banner />
       <button onClick={triggerTest}>Click to Delete Buck</button>

    </>
  );
```

I need to access returned data returned from mutation for later use. the test response/payload is not related to any other queries or types to update. It just contains status of the test and other key values that I need to save in a local state or maybe render it inside a component.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a useState inside your `onCompleted`, you'd just need to write properly. Assuming the `useState` is a call to the a React's `useState` hook, then you're probably just need to move the initialization of your state to your component.

```
const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);
const [startTestt, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(
    START_FIRE_DAMPER_TEST,
    {
      onCompleted: ({ startFireDampersTest }) =>
        console.log(startFireDampersTest.success),
        setIsSuccess(startFireDampersTest.success)
       
    },
    {
      onError: () => console.log("error!"), // never gets called
    }
  );
```